# PHP Fatal error: Class 'RemoteWebElement' not found in

Tags: facebook, symfony, phpstorm

I have a symfony project that run normal in command line:

```
php app/console server:run
```

But, I want to run inside PhpStorm. When I try to do this, it gives the fatal error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'RemoteWebElement' not found in

I already tried to look the oficial documentation of the classe:
http://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/classes/RemoteWebElement.html. But I didn't found information that culd help me.

I also added the compose dependency:

```
composer require facebook/webdriver
```

But had no effect!

=======================================

I'll explain step-step how to get this the bug (It will be very long!):

I have:

- **PHP** 5.5.9
- **PhpStorm** 10.0.3
- **composer** 1.0-dev (7117a5775ffdcdfd31bbd52a138a6f9c65e7e3c2) 2016-02-03

So, create a new symfony project (current version 3.0) and add composer dependencies:

```
symfony new project
cd project
composer update
```

Then, open this project inside of phpstorm and I configure settings for to run the project:

**Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP**

"PHP language level": **5.5**

"Interpreter": **5.5.9**

Add through plus(+) the PHP folder:

**/usr/share/php**

Click 'OK'

Now, try to run de project through PhpStorm by the shortcut:
**Ctrl+Shif+F10**.

Will appear the bug:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase' not found in

Solve this by this way inside of PhpStorm:
**Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> PHPUnit**
Choose: "Use custom autoloader"
And, in the field "Path to script", informe the autoloader's address. For example:
**/home/murilo/git/slu/app/autoload.php**. Click 'OK'.

Again, try to run de project through PhpStorm by the shortcut:

**Ctrl+Shif+F10**

Will appear the bug:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Tests\Common\Cache\CacheTest' not
>   found in

Solve this through this command inside the project folder:

```
composer require maslosoft/cachetest:dev-master -n --no-progress
```

For the last time, try to run de project through PhpStorm by the shortcut:
**Ctrl+Shif+F10**

Will appear the bug:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'RemoteWebElement' not found in

I'm at this bug.

Please, someone knows how I can overcome this bug? o.O

Comment: explain your technical context work in dev for helping you

Comment: Possibly a namespace/use issue but you've not really given enough information.

Comment: Thank for yours comments! Now I edited my question for explain better.

Comment: some more help or comment?  =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with the same exact issue as you have described. After breaking my head for most of the day with this problem, I found the issue.

When you execute the command `php app/console server:run` in command line, it sets up a server and runs the website. However, when you run the project in PHPStorm, it doesn't actually run it as a server but runs it as a PHPUnit. What you need to do is configure a PHP Web Application in PHPStorm and run that.

Check the image below where I have configured the website. When I run the Web Application, it will run by the url and it will show up in your browser.

[image: configuration window]

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I did what you said and it didn't run. Could you describe with more details what you did?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Was busy with work. Follow these steps.

1) Go to Run -> Edit Configurations. You will see PHPUnit there (not under defaults but seperately). Delete the configuration you have there by selecting it and clicking on the - button at the top. Any other ones you have also should be deleted.
2) Then Click on the + button at the top. It will show up this menu as shown above. Select PHP Web Application.
3) It will open up the screen as you see above. Give a name like "web". Select your server and confirm that URL is correct. Click OK.
4) Go to Run -> Run. Select "web".

Comment: It's OK. Thanks for your atentition. You said ".. and confirm that URL is correct". What URL shold I use? When I run directly by terminal, I use the command: "sudo php app/console server:run". So I put this URL in the browser "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/". It works! But I don't know to use inside the "Run/Debug Configurations". I tried the same URL, but it didn't run. Could you give me some more help?

Comment: ok. Need to explain you that bit. Basically when you run the command "sudo php app/console server:run", it is running in an internal server. Do you have an Apache server installed and running in your machine? Is it Windows or Unix or Mac?

Comment: Yes, I have Apache running. My OS is Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: Cool. So your localhost is pointed to your Apache server I presume. You need to setup a virtual host for your PHP Website. Check this URL. http://www.unixmen.com/setup-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-15-10/
Once you setup your virtual host, go ahead and configure it in your PHPStorm (see the dropdown in my screenshot that says server? click the button next to it which will give you the screen to setup the url related to your application). Once you have the site configured, then it will work when you click Run like I instructed above.

Comment: Ok. I did exactly like the tutorial teaches and the example works. Then I put the URL in phpstorm and clicked run. Then I saw that it just opened the Example I had just set up.

Comment: Then I replaced the folder "**public_html**" (created in the example you provided) for a shortcut to the folder of my new symfony project "**project**". After running the phpstorm, the browser only showed the contents of the project folder. I also tried for the web folder of symfony project "**project/web**", but it worked the same way.

Comment: Now, I'm thinking that what I really need is to run by the PHPUnit.

Comment: When you created the virtual host, are you pointing to the root folder of the project? If you do, then it will not work. You need to point to the web folder in your virtualhost. The url "http://symfonydemo.localhost" in my screenshot above is pointing to the "project/web" folder.

Comment: Running PHPUnit doesn't open the website. All it does is check if all the test scripts you have in your project executes successfully. And in the demo, it does. So you can't view the website through browser in PHPUnit.

Comment: My solution should resolve your problem. Kindly mark this as the answer. If you have further questions, feel free to contact me and I will guide you through anyway I can.

Comment: Hi Plague, thanks a lot for you attention and patience.
Unfornetly, running PHPUnit, it tries to open the website and show its content (files and folders). I'm pointing to '**project/web**' (like you said).
I think that what you did and runs is to another objective. Is it?
**Today, I discovered that the new symfony project uses phpunit in many places in its code.**
So, now I'm convised that to run/debug a symfony project inside phpstorm is not by this way (PHP Web Application), but by 'PHPUnit'.

Comment: I installed phpunit in my system and I'm trying configure it inside php.ini. I guess it's the way.

Comment: phpunit is testing scripts. The sample project and even fresh symfony project will have a phpunit with it because you will see a testcontroller there. But it is not the way to run/debug the project. It is for Unit Testing. Completely different purpose. 

This is leading towards a different discussion from your initial question. So kindly mark this as an answer since my response would fix your initial issue. Message me in skype (plague.y3k) and I will guide you to the right way to get this working.